# Calculation within the subquery, substract an amount from a different table

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have been working on this query for over a day now.

From the Total column in the first query (Calls) below, I need to add or subtract the Amount number from the second table (CallsIncrease) only to the months within the date range (from StartDate to EndDate where the skill equals the skill in the query).

I tried to create a field first with the Amount to subtract for each month, to then use it to subtract from the total.

I tried different versions of the the sub-queries below:

```
Expr1: (
  select amount 
  from (
    SELECT CallsIncrease.Skill, Sum(CallsIncrease.Amount) AS Amount
    FROM CallsIncrease
    GROUP BY CallsIncrease.Skill
  )
  where [skill]=(select [skill] from CallsIncrease)
    And [callmonth] Between (select [startdate] from CallsIncrease)
      And (select [enddate] from CallsIncrease)
)


Expr1: (
  SELECT Sum([%$##@_Alias].amount) AS SumOfamount
  FROM (
    SELECT CallsIncrease.Skill, Sum(CallsIncrease.Amount) AS Amount
    FROM CallsIncrease
    GROUP BY CallsIncrease.Skill)  AS [%$##@_Alias]
    GROUP BY [%$##@_Alias].skill
    HAVING ((([%$##@_Alias].skill)=forecast.skill))
)
```

**The SQL for the Calls query:**

```
SELECT
  CDate(DateSerial(Year([ForecastDate]),Month([ForecastDate]),1)) AS ForecastMonth,
  Forecast.Skill,
  Sum(Forecast.NormalizedData) AS Total
FROM Forecast
GROUP BY CDate(DateSerial(Year([ForecastDate]),Month([ForecastDate]),1)),
  Forecast.Skill
HAVING (((Sum(Forecast.NormalizedData)) Is Not Null));
```

**Calls Query:**

```
ForecastMonth   Skill               Total
01-Jan-08   Generalist English      56541
01-Jan-08   Generalist Spanish      868
01-Jan-08   Public Safety English   26837
01-Jan-08   Public Safety Spanish   401
01-Jan-08   Total                   34584
01-Jan-08   Utilities English       48332
01-Jan-08   Utilities Spanish       1605
01-Feb-08   Generalist English      52176
```

**Calls Increase Table:**

```
ID  EventID             Skill        StartDate  EndDate     Amount
1   9/5/2008    Generalist English  01-Jan-08   31-Aug-08   1800
3   7/10/2010   Generalist English  01-Jan-08   30-Jun-10   -3000
4   12/1/2011   Generalist English  01-Jan-08   30-Nov-11   2500
5   3/1/2013    Generalist English  01-Jan-08   28-Feb-13   200
6   12/1/2011   Generalist Spanish  01-Jan-08   30-Nov-11   80
7   7/1/2010    Public Safety Eng   01-Jan-08   30-Jun-10   -4700
8   3/10/2009   Utilities English   01-Jan-08   28-Feb-09   7000
```

I really hope this all makes sense, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Is this MS Access?

Comment: Yes it is MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following horrendous mess.  There is some hope that your DBMS's query optimizer can do something reasonable with it, in part because it avoids correlated subqueries.  Indeed, there is even some hope that your DBMS will accept the query more or less as written.

```
SELECT
  MonthlyForecast.Month AS ForecastMonth,
  MonthlyForecast.Skill AS Skill,
  (MonthlyForecast.Total + COALESCE(Adjustment.Amount, 0)) AS Total

FROM

  (SELECT
      CDate(DateSerial(Year([ForecastDate]),Month([ForecastDate]),1)) AS Month,
      Forecast.Skill AS Skill,
      SUM(Forecast.NormalizedData) AS Total
    FROM Forecast
    GROUP BY [Month], [Skill]
    HAVING Total IS NOT NULL
  ) MonthlyForecast

  LEFT OUTER JOIN

    (SELECT
        ForecastMonths.Month AS Month,
        CallsIncrease.Skill AS Skill,
        SUM(CallsIncrease.Amount) AS Amount
      FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
          CDate(DateSerial(Year([ForecastDate]),Month([ForecastDate]),1)) AS Month
          FROM Forecast
        ) ForecastMonths 
        JOIN CallsIncrease
          ON ForecastMonths.Month
            Between CallsIncrease.StartDate And CallsIncrease.EndDate
      GROUP BY
        [Month], [Skill]
    ) Adjustment

    ON MonthlyForecast.Month = Adjustment.Month
      AND MonthlyForecast.Skill = Adjustment.Skill
;
```

For what it's worth, the need to compare specific dates to a date range is a significant complicating factor, both for designing the query and for running it.  There are other ways to handle that problem than the one I've used above, but I'm doubtful that any of them yield a simpler query.